# How to get bootstrap html elements positioned on a single line

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to create a site header like the one on stackoverflow..

I am using bootstrap but can't seem to get the header elements to appear on a single line.

Anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/31wxk9ak/2/ . depending on the size of your screen you may need to adjust the page split on this page in order to prevent you browser from stacking the elements.

[Desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGw0y.png)

Here is the code:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="root">
    <div data-reactroot="" class="container fill">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><span
                            class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                            class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a></div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a title="About" href="/about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Contact" href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                                    placeholder="Search..."
                                                                    value=""><span class="input-group-btn"><input
                                            type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Go!"></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li id="nav-login-btn"><a title="Login" class="animate" href="/login">Login</a></li>
                        <li id="nav-login-btn"><a title="Register" class="animate" href="/register">Register</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js'>

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at Bootstrap navbar [**examples**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/#navbars). They should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not implementing the navbar properly, use a form for the search box.

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </li>
              <li id="nav-login-btn"><a title="Login" class="animate" href="/login">Login</a></li>
              <li id="nav-login-btn"><a title="Register" class="animate" href="/register">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**Reference:**

1. [Bootstrap Navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously many ways to do this, but I'll just show a couple. The first one uses floating, simply apply this to all navbar headers.

```
.navBarHeader {
    float: left;
}
```

Alternately, you can use inline-block.

```
.navBarHeader {
    display: inline-block;
}
```